# How to fix "403 insufficient authentication scopes" when uploading file [PYTHON]

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to save some `.json` files to my google drive whenever I close my program. However, I receive this error: 
`HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?fields=id&alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">`

I started with this module ~30 minutes ago and am working with what I found on the website, so it might be glaringly obvious, but here is my code:

```py
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

store = file.Storage('credentials.json')

creds = None
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# updating function
async def googledriveupdate(file):

    file_metadata = {'name': file}
    media = MediaFileUpload('{}'.format(file),
                            mimetype='application/json')
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                        media_body=media,
                                        fields='id').execute()
    print('File ID: ' + file.get('id'))
```

The idea is that whenever I close the program, this function will get called and all my files will be updated. However, I receive the 403 error and can't seem to fix it. Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: I think that your scope can upload files to Google Drive. Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, for example, how about this flow? 1. Remove ``token.pickle`` file. 2. Run the script and authorize the scopes again. By this, new ``token.pickle`` is created and the refresh token including the scopes is used. Can you confirm this? By the way, you try to upload the file to your Google Drive. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, this solution worked! Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Can you post the solution as an answer and accept it? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was not my scope, however my pickle file.

If you also have this issue, try **deleting your pickle file, and run the program again** - this worked for me